# IN with linq to object

Tags: c#-3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shorthand conditional in C# similar to SQL 'in' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32937/shorthand-conditional-in-c-sharp-similar-to-sql-in-keyword)

I have a string variable which holds states. I want to check whether it equals to one of these three. I want it to work the way IN works in SQL Server. IS it possible to do with Linq to Objects.

i want

```
if(str IN ("WA","CA","CO"))
{

}
else
{

}
```

How to do it. I donot want to use multiple OR conditions.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately there is no IN, but you can say this

```
if (new[] { "WA", "CA", "CO" }.Contains(str))
{
}
```

It seems the wrong way around but it's the best we've got.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if ((new string [] {"WA", "CA", "CO"}).Contains(str))
{
}
else
{
}
```

This is using the .Contains() extension method on IEnumerable<> - not full LINQ but it should work. In production code you'd want to extract the array

```
new string[] {"WA", "CA", "CO"}
```

out to a local field.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {

   public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] options) : where T : IComparable<T> {
      foreach (T option in options) {
         if (value.CompareTo(option) == 0) return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

}
```

Usage:

```
var result = someCollection.Where(x => x.Property.In(1,2,3));
```